# ReleaseMutex fails without setting an error code

Tags: c++, windows

I have a couple of applications with multiple threads trying to get access to the same mutex some time during the execution. What I have noticed is that sometimes the thread that owns the mutex and then tries to release it fails to do so (ReleaseMutex returns 0) but no error code is set. This problem appears to happen randomly and it happens several times during the execution of my applications. It seems the mutex gets released even if ReleaseMutex fails though because my applications continue to run normally from what I can tell.

Does anyone have any idea what could be causing ReleaseMutex to fail and not set an error code? I have made sure to call GetLastError directly after ReleaseMutex fails to make sure no other method is changing the error code.

EDIT: Added the code I use to release the mutex and then get the error code if it fails.

```
// Release
mutexResult = ReleaseMutex(dataMutex);
if(!mutexResult)
{
    char text[200];
    DWORD err = GetLastError();
    sprintf(text, "Release mutex error = %d!\n", err);
    TRACE(text);
}
```

I can add that the code above is included in a function that first acquires the mutex and then does some work on the protected data before it releases the mutex again. This function is called from multiple places in each process but everytime I get this strange problem it is the same call (specific line in one of my source files) to this function that causes it. All other calls to it seem to work fine.

Comment: Standard C++ has std::lock_guard and std::unique_lock, both auto unlocks a mutex upon destruction so that you don't need to worry about calling ReleaseMutex explicitly. Not an answer to your question. Just FYI.

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem under WinDbg? If so, set a breakpoint when `ReleaseMutex` failed and dump out the offending mutex using `!handle <mutex_handle> 7` command in WinDbg.

Comment: What you describe should not be possible. If `ReleaseMutex()` fails, `GetLastError()` is always set, so the only way it could be returning 0 is if something is resetting it before you call it

Comment: Could be faulty third-party software interfering.  Are you able to try this on a cleanly installed machine?  Are you *absolutely certain* that the call to GetLastError() is happening directly after the call to ReleaseMutex(), i.e., something like `DWORD dw = GetLastError();` and not a more complicated statement?

Comment: Thanks for the replies, I have added the code I use to release the mutex and retrieve the error code. I also added some other info as well. The error code is supposed to be thread specific right so any other thread or process should not be able to interfere? I don't think I have used WinDbg before, is it used from Visual Studio or is it a separate tool?

Comment: Pre-existing stack corruption perhaps?  Are you able to provide a [mcve]?

Comment: It's a long shot, but try `if (!ReleaseMutex(dataMutex)` and/or `static char text[200];`

Comment: I appear to have found the problem, it is a bit embarrassing that I did not see it before but in my defence I didn't write the code. :) The `mutexResult` variable was a global variable and the same variable was used to store the result of `WaitForSingleObject`. So I believe that sometimes (seemingly random) after storing the return value of ReleaseMutex but before executing the if-statement some other thread interrupted and set the `mutexResult` variable to the return value of `WaitForSingleObject` now that it could acquire the mutex.

Comment: I know you've already found the problem, but I encountered the same thing and I want to leave a comment anyway for future reference.
For me the problem was that the mutex was already released, by a different handle to the same name, on the same thread.